# Active Directory: RPC Issues, Trust between 2003 and 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, port, windows-server-2003-r2, trust-relationship

I've been having this ongoing issue that has been plaguing me. I am in charge of two domains:

DOMAIN1 - Functional Level 2003

DOMAIN2 - Functional Level 2012

I was able to establish the trust between the two domains successfully as it is a two-way external non-transitive trust. Since then however, I have been having issues. Attempting to open Active Directory Users & Computers from DOMAIN1 and connect to DOMAIN2, I will get several different error messages such as access denied, RPC Server Unavailable, or that I have reached the timeout period. Performing the same from DOMAIN2 to DOMAIN1 works fine.

I have verified with the firewall team that the ports are open, but when using PortqryUI I have issues when it scans Port 135. It begins listing all of the UUIDs, then stops randomly and doesn't provide anymore information. I'm worried I may have a UUID issue on DOMAIN2 domain controller but am not sure.

Does anyone have any idea what this could be?

Thanks!

Comment: Compatibility between Server operating systems made nearly 10 years after each other is very intermittent. Microsoft do not recommend that you use Server 2003 as it is EOL and unsupported so most ways to link the DC's will be deprecated. What is the need to link them anyway?

Comment: In the grand scheme of things we presently have three separate domains that are going to migrate into one. Two domains are at FFL 2003 due to the age of the equipment that we have in production that can't be replaced. As the two domains are going to migrate into the third, we want to ensure we have the two way trust so that we can implement and test migration of machines into that domain without issues.